# Mule esb 3.5 zip file

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule-esb

My Mule run as service mode

I have one app test in ~/test/mule and an other app prod in ~/prod/mule

Before, when I was deploying my project by deploy.sh (mvn clean install -P ${ENV}) a zip file was created in the commun folder /soft/mule-standalone-3.5.0/apps and Mule updated the application. It like this I do update of my Mule.
This worked until Friday 08.

Now when a .zip is in the /apps, Mule do nothing.

I deleted the anchor.txt file and its folder. The appliation print errors messages and I uploada new zip file in /soft/mule-standalone-3.5.0/apps folder, but there is still nothing going on.
best regard.

### Mule status

```
 ./mule status
 Mule is running (23770).
```

### Maven log

> DEPLOY ###### [INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Building middleware-services 2.2.0 [INFO]
>
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @
> middleware-services --- [INFO] Deleting
> /home/aeschbach/test/mule/target [INFO] [INFO] ---
> maven-mule-plugin:1.9:attach-test-resources
> (default-attach-test-resources) @ middleware-services --- [INFO]
> attaching test resource /home/aeschbach/test/mule/src/main/app [INFO]
> [INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.7:add-resource (add-resource) @
> middleware-services --- [INFO] [INFO] ---
> maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @
> middleware-services --- [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered
> resources. [INFO] Copying 11 resources [INFO] Copying 4 resources
> [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory
> /home/aeschbach/test/mule/src/main/api [INFO] Copying 3 resources
> [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-mule-plugin:1.9:filter-resources
> (default-filter-resources) @ middleware-services --- [INFO] [INFO] ---
> maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @
> middleware-services --- [INFO] Compiling 169 source files to
> /home/aeschbach/test/mule/target/classes [INFO] [INFO] ---
> maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:testResources (default-testResources) @
> middleware-services --- [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered
> resources. [INFO] Copying 0 resource [INFO] Copying 4 resources [INFO]
> [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile
> (default-testCompile) @ middleware-services --- [INFO] Compiling 2
> source files to /home/aeschbach/test/mule/target/test-classes [INFO]
> [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) @
> middleware-services ---
>
> -------------------------------------------------------  T E S T S
>
> ---
>
> Results :
>
> Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
>
> [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-mule-plugin:1.9:mule (default-mule) @
> middleware-services --- [INFO] Copying classes directly [INFO] Adding
> org.apache.pdfbox:jempbox:jar:1.8.9 as a lib [INFO] Adding
> com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.5.13 as a lib [INFO] Adding
> commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1 as a lib [INFO] Adding
> org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:jar:1.8.9 as a lib [INFO] Adding
> org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.10 as a lib [INFO] Adding
> commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4 as a lib [INFO] Adding
> com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.11.0 as a lib
> [INFO] Adding org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.5 as a lib [INFO]
> Adding net.sf.barcode4j:barcode4j:jar:2.1 as a lib [INFO] Adding
> org.jvnet:mimepull:jar:1.6 as a lib [INFO] Adding
> mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.6 as a lib [INFO] Adding
> org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.6 as a lib [INFO]
> Adding com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.42 as a lib [INFO] Adding
> com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.11.0 as a lib [INFO]
> Adding com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.11.0 as
> a lib [INFO] Adding org.apache.pdfbox:fontbox:jar:1.8.9 as a lib
> [INFO] Adding com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-multipart:jar:1.6 as a
> lib [INFO] Adding com.oracle:ojdbc:jar:8 as a lib [INFO] Copying
> mappings [INFO] Building zip:
> /home/aeschbach/test/mule/target/middleware-services-test.zip [INFO]
> already added, skipping [INFO] [INFO] ---
> maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @
> middleware-services --- [INFO] No primary artifact to install,
> installing attached artifacts instead. [INFO] Installing
> /home/aeschbach/test/mule/pom.xml to
> /home/aeschbach/.m2/repository/ch/koala/middleware-services/2.2.0/middleware-services-2.2.0.pom
> [INFO] Installing
> /home/aeschbach/test/mule/target/middleware-services-test.zip to
> /home/aeschbach/.m2/repository/ch/koala/middleware-services/2.2.0/middleware-services-2.2.0.zip
> [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-mule-plugin:1.9:install (default-install) @
> middleware-services --- [INFO] Copying
> /home/aeschbach/test/mule/target/middleware-services-test.zip to
> /soft/mule-standalone-3.5.0/apps/middleware-services-test.temp [INFO]
> Renaming
> /soft/mule-standalone-3.5.0/apps/middleware-services-test.temp to
> /soft/mule-standalone-3.5.0/apps/middleware-services-test.zip [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 9.566s [INFO] Finished at: Wed Oct 14 11:47:03 CEST
> 2020 [INFO] Final Memory: 52M/709M [INFO]
>
> ---
>
> test - DEPLOYMENT SUCCESS

### Mule.log

> Message               : Failed to invoke
> JerseyResourcesComponent{restWebServices.component.394477431}.
> Component that caused exception is:
> JerseyResourcesComponent{restWebServices.component.394477431}. Message
> payload is of type: String Type                  :
> org.mule.component.ComponentException Code                  :
> MULE_ERROR--2 JavaDoc               :
> http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/component/ComponentException.html
> Payload               : /rest/v1/doc
> ******************************************************************************** Exception stack is:
>
> 1. null (java.lang.NullPointerException)   java.io.Reader:78 (null)
> 2. Failed to invoke JerseyResourcesComponent{restWebServices.component.394477431}.
>    Component that caused exception is:
>    JerseyResourcesComponent{restWebServices.component.394477431}. Message
>    payload is of type: String (org.mule.component.ComponentException)
>    org.mule.component.AbstractComponent:144
>    (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/component/ComponentException.html)
>    ******************************************************************************** Root Exception stack trace: java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>    java.io.Reader.(Reader.java:78)     at
>    java.io.InputStreamReader.(InputStreamReader.java:72)   at
>    ch.koala.utils.Util.getStringFromInputStream(Util.java:58)    at
>    ch.koala.services.RestServices.getAPIDoc(RestServices.java:1320)  at
>    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor740.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:187)
>    at
>    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:71)
>    at
>    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:280)
>    at
>    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>    at
>    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
>    at
>    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>    at
>    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
>    at
>    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1341)
>    at
>    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1273)
>    at
>    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1223)
>    at
>    org.mule.module.jersey.JerseyResourcesComponent.doInvoke(JerseyResourcesComponent.java:159)
>    at
>    org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.invokeInternal(AbstractComponent.java:122)
>    at
>    org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.access$000(AbstractComponent.java:57)
>    at
>    org.mule.component.AbstractComponent$1$1.process(AbstractComponent.java:238)
>    at
>    org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
>    at
>    org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
>    at
>    org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
>    at
>    org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:51)
>    at
>    org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
>    at
>    org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
>    at
>    org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
>    at
>    org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
>    at
>    org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
>    at
>    org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
>    at
>    org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.process(AbstractComponent.java:156)
>    at
>    org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
>    at
>    org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
>    at
>    org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
>    at
>    org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
>    at
>    org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
>    at
>    org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:97)
>    at
>    org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
>    at
>    org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
>    at
>    org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
>    at
>    org.mule.construct.DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.process(DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.java:54)
>    at
>    org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
>    at
>    org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
>    at
>    org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
>    at
>    org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.jav...
>
> ---

Comment: you may want to add what do you expect to happen after deployment.

Comment: Hello,

Tks for your answer.

The goal is to update my program.

It used to work great but befor but now it doesn't

Comment: look for any deployments related messages in the mule_ee.log and edit your question to add the details in text. There may be an error, or at least to see if it is deploying as expected.

Comment: Tks for your answer,

I will did it